# simplification question on Diff. Eq. Solution

Tags: algebra-precalculus, ordinary-differential-equations

[image]

Can anyone explain this simplification from y^-2 to y? If you distribute the x^4 through, you obtain y^-2 = (2/x) + Cx^4. This leads to y^2 will equal the reciprocal of what I just wrote. Where in the world does Cx^5 come from in the final solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$y^{-2}=x^4\left(\frac2{x^5}+c_1\right)=\frac xxx^4\left(\frac2{x^5}+c_1\right)=\frac1x\left(2+c_1x^5\right)$$
$$y=\left[\frac1x\left(2+c_1x^5\right)\right]^{-\frac12}=\left[\frac x{\left(2+c_1x^5\right)}\right]^{\frac12}=\frac{\sqrt x}{\sqrt{2+c_1x^5}}$$